# Programmatic LESS imports

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, less, dotless

Is there any way to tell less to import different external files based on something pragmatically?

I process my LESS with dotless, but can't find anything that hints towards this being possible.

EDIT:  Also just so this info is available.  I'm aware of how to import specific files into another file.  My question is the ability to specify a file to import based on some other piece of data....the users role...status of something....etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you cannot just do something this, while generating your LESS file with ASP:

```
If userRole1 Then     

  code to load imports for userRole1   

Else    

  code to load default imports

End If
```

In other words, generate your LESS file with ASP, accessing what you need, then have it output the LESS code with the desired imports, then LESS takes over to build the CSS.

Comment: This. Just remember to cache your generated LESS file for each variant.

Comment: The point is that LESS will return a SINGLE file when it handles the imports.  I can already programmatically determine a CSS/LESS file(s) to include in a view.  I'm hoping to let `.less{}` handle the determining what to include so that a single file with the correct values is returned.

Comment: Also I'm not generating the LESS myself.  I simply have a handler in the `web.config` to hand the `.less` extension with `.less{}` (couldn't tell if I had conveyed that in the question well or not)

Comment: @ScottS Are you assuming a client side LESS processor?  It just seems like if I'm building these out of a composition of existing less files and using something like dotless... Would I not need to leave the file that I generate on the server somewhere? or could this simply be a memory stream?  I guess I'm just not seeing how this could work based on dotless as the processor.

Comment: @Jared: I am by no means an ASP expert (not even really a novice). My point was to use ASP (which I assume has the settings you want to read) to generate the LESS server-side, which is then processed through either a LESS preprocessor server-side or client-side. But that LESS file would only be importing the files needed based off the settings of ASP.